# Create an indicator variable in SparklyR when all the variables are missing

Tags: r, na, sparklyr, dplyr, rowsum

I am trying to use rowSum in sparklyr to create an indicator variable where all the variables are missing but it seems that rowSum doesn't work in sparklyr.

I have to write the name of all the variables in is.na() function like below which is impossible since I have 100 variables.

```
y <- c(NA,1,2)
x <- c(NA,NA,3)
z <- c(NA,NA,NA)
dt = data.frame(x,y,z)

sdf_copy_to(sc, dt)

dt %>% 
 mutate(new = ifelse(is.na(x) & is.na(y) & is.na(z), 1,0))
```

Is there anyway to write multiple variables in is.na() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(rlang)
library(glue)
```

1. create a string with all the variable names of interest. 
   I am calling all of them for simplicity; use regex (e.g., `grep`) otherwise

   ```
   cols_of_interest <- names(dt)


   test_string <-  glue("ifelse({glue('is.na({cols_of_interest})') %>% 
   glue_collapse(sep = '&')}, yes = 1, no = 0)")
   ```
2. parse the string with `rlang`

   ```
   dt %>% mutate(flag = !!rlang::parse_expr(test_string))
   ```

Comment: It works pretty well!Exactly what I was looking for.